# Aprilaire 600 to Fedders furnace

Tags: wiring, hvac, furnace, humidifier

Wiring issue.  I have installed the unit, an Aprilaire 600. When the humidifier is OFF, the heat and fan operate normally. However, when the humidifier is ON, the heat and fan come on normally but when the heat turns off, the fan does not turn off, neither does the humidifier.  I have attached the diagrams I have use in wiring the unit. The question(s) I have is/are:  When I connected the R and C from the furnace  to the humidistat, the humidistat would not power up --voltage available is only 6 volts. So I connected the R to R and the C to T on the furnace terminal strip. This powered the humidistat and I ran the various tests. Humidifier comes on when furnace/fan comes on. Turning fan switch to OFF, shuts humidifier off. Turning dial to OFF turns humidifier off. Running TEST/RESET works exactly (both when the blower switch is OFF and when it is ON) as it should --(humidifier comes on) green light comes on, then flashes, the turns the humidifier off. The resistance of the Outside Temperature Sensor matches the appropriate value as listed on the chart. The solenoid valve seems to operate normally --water flows when it should and does not flow when it shouldn't. The only issue is when the furnace cycles ON and then OFF --the furnace blower (not the heat) stays on --the humidifier itself also stays on.

[image: Thermostat wiring option one]
[image: Thermostat wiring option two --I used option two]
[image: Aprilaire wiring]
[image: Fedders furnace wiring]
[image: Fedders furnace terminal strip]

Comment: An [edit] to apply some formatting, or at least line breaks would make that much easier to read.

Comment: As I recall that humidistat can be configured so that it'll run the fan whenever the humidity is too low, which may or may not be during a heat cycle. Could this be what's happening? Also - your furnace controls really run on 6 volts? AC or DC? You may want to call Aprilaire and inquire whether their humidistat is compatible with that voltage. If it isn't you'll need a different control or possibly some extra relays.

Comment: Thank you.  Most helpful.  I suspect you are correct --Aprilaire unit has fan on and fan off switch. Now works with heat only (fan off) with fan on, runs nearly constantly because humidity is below set point.